# Where we need to maintain jwt token in server side

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

what is the best practices to handling JWT in server side

1) I saw lots of code.they are maintained in database .is it good practice?

2) can we maintain as session value?

How we should implement JWT in server side in spring boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. The whole point of a JWT is to contain everything in the JWT itself to be able to identify the user. There is no reason to store a JWT at server-side (unless you want to somehow maintain a list of blacklisted/revoked JWTs, but even then, an ID or something inside the JWT should be sufficient).
2. No. The whole point of a JWT is to contain everything in the JWT itself to be able to identify the user. And this is precisely what allows avoiding sessions, and to be completely stateless: you receive the JWT, and if you know the secret key used to sign it, you can know who the user is, and be sure the JWT hasn't been counterfeited.

I think you need to understand what a JWT is, and how they work. Why do you want to store JWTs?